# DOS Batch file to find "new" files by date

Tags: command-line, batch, find, disk-operating-system

My PC has entered an infinite BSOD loop - but I do have access to a safe-mode command prompt.

I'm trying to get an idea of "what changed" that might have triggered this. e.g. I might have gotten a virus, or an app update went belly up.

I'd like to thus see which files were created/modified in the last few days/week or at least the *.exe, *.dll, *.com, *.bat etc.

I thought I was ok with my Batch-fu but I'm stumped on how to write a quick batch file/command that would list the files for me.

```
REM This will find the files, but the results are all muddled
REM all EXE files, reverse sort by date, recursively through sub-directories

dir *.exe /O-D /S
```

What I'd really like is to find all (executable filetypes) that were created/modified in the last 3-7 days.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Totally separate from the command to run, it sounds like there is a corrupted setting someone, not an additional executable (which is what your script would find).

Comment: @soandos - quite possible, I'm going to guess that something I installed or updated... is what triggered the setting change.  Either way I think a quick batch file for the above scenario would still be a really handy tool.

Comment: @Todd, have you tried booting from Last Known Good Configuration?  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-Last-Known-Good-Configuration (same concept applies to WinXP/2003)

Comment: Why don't you analyze the memory dump from the BSOD?

Comment: @ZippyV - I suppose I could but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I tried to do `edit c:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP` but it said it was (and I quote) "Out to far Memory"

Comment: @Todd McArthur http://www.theexperienceblog.com/technical-articles/troubleshooting-and-analyzing-blue-screens-of-death/

Comment: -1 "an infinite BSOD loop"  <-- as if that's a technical term.  "but I do have access to a safe-mode command prompt."  not within a BSOD though. So you mean your computer keeps going into a BSOD each time it's started/restarted. i.e. it's not an intermittent problem. You have a stupid way of putting it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is a simple, albeit roundabout way, using xcopy.  you can look at `xcopy /?` to see the switches etc.

```
xcopy \windows\*.exe /L /S /D:12-01-2000 .
```

This command will output a list of `.EXE` files and paths in the `\windows` folder recursively, that were modified on or after 12/1/2000, without actually copying them.  NOTE there is a period at then end of the command.  Its hard to see with a small font.

Edit 1:  I took out the `/F` from the original command, as it was extraneous.

Edit 2:  You can pipe the output to "`| more`" if you want

Comment: just before I jump on this... which part is the part that says "don't actually copy"?  ... is it the `.` e.g. copy to the files original position?

Comment: /L just lists, not copies

Comment: @Todd McArthur do xcopy /? man

Comment: @barlop - yeah I didn't realize the lowercase l was an l vs. a # 1.  Also since xcopy is normally for copying - the last thing I wanted to do would be to blast copies of my files across my drive ;-)

Comment: xcopy is a great, yet underutilized tool, in Windows.  xxcopy, a 3rd party program is even better.  http://www.xxcopy.com/xcpymain.htm

Comment: +1! Great use of it, I thought I'd have to parse a `DIR` command, but this is perfect!

Comment: Elegant. Thanks. I piped the results to a file with `> results.txt`. Note, if you run the command in the folder you are `xcopy`ing from then you will need to replace the last `.` with a dummy target or you will get a warning about cyclic copying.